# Want to rewrite url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to htaccess and want to do following thing,

I want to rewrite url like,

```
http://example.com/test/test.php to http://example.com/test.html
```

and my htaccess file present in test folder. Can anyone help to find out this problem.

Thank You

Comment: Will your visitors enter the PHP or the HTML address? Most of the time its the second case.

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ test/$1.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, i tried above code it it still not working. Below is my htaccess code RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/([^/\.]+)/?.php$ $1.html [L] and i am running url like http://example.com/test/test.php but it not rewrite url. Url remain same as it is. I want that url should rewrite link http://example.com/test.html